# What are the rules for the order of time adverbs?

Tags: grammar, adverbs, word-order, time

**I have some doubts about the sentence order for time adverbs.**

**Note**: [Time adverbs](https://english4today.com/grammar-topic/adverbs-of-time/) tell us *when* an action happened, but also for *how long*, and *how often*.
English examples:

- When: today, yesterday, later, now, last year.
- For how long: all day, not long, for a while, since last year.
- How often: sometimes, frequently, never, often, yearly.

---

I know the usual sentence order in Mandarin is:

1. > S + Time + VP

But when we want to put emphasis on the Time, this structure is [also allowed](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Time_words_and_word_order):

2. > Time + S + VP

However, structure 2 does not seem to apply for all *adverbs of time*. I know time adverbs expressing frequency and [duration](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_duration_with_%22le%22) follow a different pattern. But here I am thinking of time adverbs indicating *habitual actions* such as 经常 (often), 总是 (always) or 一般 (usually). For example, in  [here](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Comparing_%22changchang%22_and_%22jingchang%22) they explain we can not say structure 2:

> <strike>经常他不吃早饭</strike>
>
> Jīngcháng tā bù chī zǎo fàn.

But only structure 1:

> 他**经常**不吃早饭
>
> Tā jīngcháng  bù chī zǎo fàn.
>
> He often skips breakfast.

On the other hand, I have seen some other examples of time adverbs indicating habitual actions following structure 2 with "每 + Time + S + 都", such as:

> **每天我都**运动。
>
> Měitiān wǒ dōu yùndòng.
>
> Everyday I do exercise.

**Q1: Which adverbs of time can follow structure 2?**

---

**Q2: When there are several adverbs of time, is there a rule indicating their order?**

For example, can we rewrite the following examples:

- > **周末**我**经常**去学校。
  >
  > Zhōumò wǒ jīngcháng qù xuéxiào.
  >
  > I often go to school on weekends.

  (with time adverbs: 周末, 经常), such as:

  > 我**周末经常**去学校。?

  Or:

  > 我**经常周末**去学校。？
- > 我**一般12点**睡觉。
  >
  > Wǒ yībān 12 diǎn shuìjiào.
  >
  > I usually go to bed at 12 o'clock.

  (with time adverbs: 一般, 12点), such as:

  > 我**12点一般**睡觉。？

Comment: 都 and 不 are adverb too.

Comment: @000 I don't understand your point. My question is about adverbs of time.

Comment: I have a feeling that it can be very helpful if you provide the definition of adverb of time or time adverb.

Comment: All of 周末我经常去学校。 , 我周末经常去学校。 and 我经常周末去学校。 are understandable. 我12点一般睡觉。 is unusual.

Comment: 都 and 不 are adverb of time too according to definition given by you.

Comment: I don't see how 不 tells *when, how long or how often* an action happened. I don't understand enough 都, but I believe the structure "每 + Time + (...) + 都" is a time adverb.

Comment: Ok, maybe I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> "However, structure 2. does not seem to apply for all adverbs of time,
> in particular for some time adverbs indicating habitual actions such
> as 经常 (often), 总是 (always) or 一般 (usually). "

You probably mixed up **time words** with **frequency words**. Those are quotes from your links on "ChineseGrammarWiki":

> Remembering where to put the time words, such as "yesterday,"
> "tomorrow," "this week," etc. in a sentence is really important in
> order to speak Chinese correctly.
>
> Time words can appear in one of two positions in the sentence in Chinese: either > at the beginning of the sentence (before the subject), or directly after the
> subject. The structures are:
>
> Time + Subj. + Verb + Obj. 
> Subj. + Time + Verb + Obj.
>
> From *Time words and word order*

> "...常常 and 经常 both can be used to express frequency..."
>
> From *Comparing changchang and jingchang*

So, that answers **Q1**: 
"Which adverbs of time can follow structure 2?" 
In this case, the answer would be **"none"**, since the words mentioned in the Wiki that relate to time, are **proper nouns** (They are *names* identifying different parts of time), **not adverbs**.

Let's look at your sample sentences given in the "examples" section of "Q2":

- 周末我经常去学校
- 我一般12点睡觉

When we remove the last section from the sentences for simplicity, then identify the role of each word, we get this:

- "周末我经常"

  - "周末": *proper noun* of *time*
  - "我": *proper noun* of *subject*
  - "经常": *adverb* of *frequency*
- "我一般12点"

  - "我": *proper noun* of *subject*
  - "一般": *adverb* of *frequency*
  - "12点": *proper noun* of *time*

Because those 2 formats are accepted, without changing the meaning of the sentence, and because frequency words cannot be located at the beginning of a sentence (As mentioned in Q1), therefore, the answer to Q2: 
"When there are several adverbs of time, is there a rule indicating their order?"
is **"Yes"**.

---

Hope this helps. If not, correct me.

Comment: I believe grammatically you can consider proper nouns indicating the frequency as time adverbs. Anyway, what about the structure 每+time+S+都？Wouldn't that be a frequency word for you that is located before the subject? Is the only case where frequency words can be located before the subject?

Comment: So both the structures `S + time + frequency + VP` and `S + frequency + time + VP` are equivalent?

Comment: Hello Bryan, nice answer. Though please note that [proper nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_noun_and_common_noun) are *[names] used for an individual person, place, or organization*. "Bryan", "Puco" and 李飞 are proper nouns. *Names identifying different parts of time* are just common nouns.

Comment: @Puco4
"...Anyway, what about the structure 每+time+S+都？Wouldn't that be a frequency word for you that is located before the subject? Is the only case where frequency words can be located before the subject?"

Not exactly. "每" translates to the word "every", and the [translation](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/every) on this _does not strictly relate to time_.

Comment: @Puco4 "So both the structures `S + time + frequency + VP` and `S + frequency + time + VP` are equivalent?" The general meanings are the same. However, different parts of the sentences would be slightly emphasized. For example, `S + time + ...` emphasizes **time**, while `S + frequency + ...` emphasizes **frequency**.